# Java - searching my array list in an if statement to see if it contains a name

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, boolean

Basically I want this code to execute only when the item textBooks is in the inventory, right now it executes all the time.  I do not know what to put in the if statement because everything I do just makes the currentMessage equal to its previous value.

```
public void read(){
    boolean found = myArray.contains("textBooks");
    currentMessage = "sorry you cannot read this text book because you are not the all knowing";

}
```

Comment: did you try listeners?

Comment: no I haven't tried them

Comment: i would set a listener on inventory, that runs this code every time the inventory contents change...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(myArray.contains("textbooks"))
    currentMessage = "You may read"
else
    currentMessage = "You may not read"
```

I also suggest taking a look at the java basics over here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/

Comment: This is what I had, but it never displays the currentMessage

Comment: `System.out.println(currentMessage);`